# jquery-ui autocomplete option with rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, coffeescript

I'm beginner for jquery/coffea script in rails

how do I add option to my coffea script
so the generated html will include these options below

**autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"**

below is my coffea script that connect with this field

**order_details.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
    $('.auto_items').autocomplete
      source: $('.auto_items').data('autocomplete-source')
```

**_orderdetails_fields.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
    <%= f.text_field :item_name, data: {autocomplete_source: item_sources.order(:name).map(&:name)}, class: "auto_items ui-autocomplete-input" %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to coffeescript I guess, as its regarding html generation.

```
<%= f.text_field :item_name, data: {autocomplete_source: item_sources.order(:name).map(&:name)}, class: "auto_items ui-autocomplete-input", autocomplete: "off", role: "textbox", 'aria-autocomplete' => "list", 'aria-haspopup' => "true" %>
```

should generate proper html